# Laravel how get array and not object of QueryBuilder select() statement?

Tags: arrays, database, laravel

I have write that code but i want take an array of this, is this possible?

```
$results = DB::table('pages')->select('id', 'link')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
```

Comment: Use toArray() function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get laravel query builder result in array check this:

```
$results = DB::table('pages')->select('id', 'link')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get()->toArray();
```

Or

If you prefer to use Query Builder instead of Eloquent here is the solutions

```
$results = DB::table('pages')->select('id', 'link')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
```

**First Solution**

```
$array = (array) $result;
```

**Second Solution**

```
$array = get_object_vars($result);
```

**Third Solution**

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($result), true);
```

hope it may help

Comment: I try but... Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
HELP
Call to a member function toArray() on array

Comment: Updated to answer @user3211908

Answer (score 2):

You can see from the API [docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_get) that the `get()` function returns either a Collection or a Builder.

Laravel collections have the `toArray()` method (described in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-toarray)) as shown below:

```php
$collection = collect(['name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200]);

$collection->toArray();

/*
    [
        ['name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200],
    ]
*/
```

Therefore, you can do the following:

```
$results = DB::table('pages')->select('id', 'link')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: I try but... Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) HELP Call to a member function toArray() on array

Comment: @user3211908 Can you call `dd(DB::table('pages')->select('id', 'link')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get());` and take a screenshot, censoring sensitive info? It'd be good to see exactly what's being returned.